# Smallest possible difference between AUC of two ranker

Tags: ranking, auc, roc, learning-to-rank

If there are 10 positive examples, and 90 negative examples in the test set, what is the smallest possible difference in AUC, between two rankers giving different AUC?

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Is this homework? If yes please show your work or explain your difficulty.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is cross-posted at stats.SE: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/593871/232706